# How to fix #NAME? error with formula or vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i am using an excel formula to reference, and adjust when necessary, a very long list of scraped values. my problem is that occasionally the values start with "=+" causing them to be seen as a formula, and thus producing a #NAME? error. whenever my formula references these cells, it too produces said error.

is there anyway to account for #NAME errors within my formula? something like ISNA but for #NAME errors?

if that is not possible, could i use VBA to delete "=+" from any cells that contain it?

any help would be greatly appreciated, ive been looking for an answer to this for hours.

Comment: Fix your 'scraped values' and your formulas will be fine.

Comment: im looking for a much simpler fix than that

Comment: Have you ever heard of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) ?

Comment: nope. but adjusting the scraper isn't an option. if what im asking is not possible then I'll come up with another way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a `'` in front of each cell's formula. 
Imagining you have your scraped values in the range `C1:C10`, you can fix it like this:

```
For j = 1 To 10
    Range("C" & j).Value = "'" & Range("C" & j).Formula
Next j
```

By doing so, you preserve the original value of your scraped object. 
Of course you can fix the issue at the source, i.e. imagining you print your values like this:

```
rng.Value = myScrapedValue
```

... you can replace it like this:

```
rng.Value = quoteFirst(myScrapedValue)
```

... where

```
Private Function quoteFirst(ByVal strng As String) As String
    quoteFirst = "'" & strng
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use an =IFERROR() in your formulas directly, that would save time of developping a VBA code dedicated to this specific error.

Comment: thanks for the response. this might work, but it doesn't seem to allow for an else statement which is not ideal. so far this is the best solution ive got though.

Comment: If you actually need an else statement, you have to use `IF(ISERROR(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use something like...

=ERROR.TYPE(A1) =5

This should produce a TRUE-FALSE in the formula....

Comment: i tried that and a couple variations of that but i can only seem to get "TRUE" or "#N/A"     am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You probably need to add a little more checking ' something like...=IF(ISERROR(B6);IF(ERROR.TYPE(B6)=5;"I am a NAME error";"I am a different error");B6) If this is no error, the value will be returned, otherwise it looks at the error in question....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the "=+" you can use something like this :

```
Dim index As Integer
For index = 1 To 10
    If (Mid(Cells(index, 1), 1, 2) = "=+") Then
        Cells(index, 1) = Mid(Cells(index, 1), 3)
    End If
Next
```

It will replace the content of the cells beginning by "+=" by the same content without "+=".